# Lua - Get index of last character appearance in a string

Tags: string, lua, substring

I have some strings representing table "paths" that can be used to iterate to a value within a table, such as:

`"table.subTable[2].anotherTable"`

`"table.subTable.otherTable.anotherTable"`

`"table.subTable.otherTable[3]"`

[2] and [3] are indexes which might point to another table. I need to write a function that cuts off the last key/index so that the "string path" points to the previous (or "parent") table.

For example, the above strings should turn into:

`"table.subTable[2]"`

`"table.subTable.otherTable"`

`"table.subTable.otherTable"`

I thought this could be done by finding the last `[` or `.` characters in the string and splitting it by using `string.sub`.

There might be many other ways to achieve this, such as `gmatch`, but I'm not sure how. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `.` and `[` only occur in indexing syntax in the strings you are working with, you can do `path:match('(.+)[.[]')`. `[.[]` is visually confusing, but it is a set containing `.` and `[`. You can escape `[` with a percent (`[.%[]`), but it isn't necessary.

If one of the table indices is a string that contains `.` or `[`, like `table['sub.table'][3]`, this solution will fail. In that case, the solution would be more complicated. You could use LPeg, or replace `.` or `[` within strings with some other sequence of characters before doing the string matching and then restore the `.` or `[` after the string matching.

Comment: thanks! The table indices will not contain `.` or `[` so that will work. Not exactly sure why `[[.]` is fine but switching the characters around requires a `%` like `[.^[]`.

Comment: Oh, right, the `[` doesn't have to be escaped (though the pattern is visually confusing). I've edited my post.